# How to cancel authorization to filter network content in Macbook?

Tags: network

I'm currently using Kaspersky on my macbook. I only want to use its file anti-virus feature, but it forces me to allow it to filter network content. I emailed Kaspersky officials and they said it was necessary and this feature cannot be turned off individually.

So I want to ask if there is a way to revoke the authorization of an application to allow filter network content on Macbook?

[image]
[image]

Comment: Seriously, I'd get rid of Kapersky. There is much more risk using it than not. There are plenty of other products.

Comment: Why is this? Also, what file antivirus software do you recommend on MacOS?

Comment: Too much for a comment: but Kapersky is a Russian company, and there are concerns about whether it can entirely be trusted, given the Kremlin's use of cyber-warfare against the West. Secondly, the nature of malware is not what is was, and the traditional AV software paradigm is somewhat dated. Malwarebytes is a good recommendation.

Comment: Maybe you're right. Thanks for the recommendation, I'll probably try Malwarebytes.

Answer (score 2):

Go to System Settings → Network → Filters and disable or delete the network filter.

[image]

[image]

---

Prior to Ventura, filters show as a network service. In System Preferences → Network, choose the network filter in the list of services on the left, then either

- disable the service by choosing ‘Make Service Inactive’ from the ⋯ button at the bottom of the service list, or
- delete the service by choosing the – button at the bottom of the service list.

Comment: Thank you so much bro, but due to the past performance of MacOS, I dare not use versions earlier than x.6 in my work environment. So I'm still using Monterey. I think this should be a new feature of Venture, because I can't find a similar setting in my System Settings. Anyway, at least I know this setting is supported on newer MacOS versions.

Comment: @AppleGreen Added instructions for older macOS. I don't have screenshots and going off memory as I don't have access to a Mac with older macOS.

Comment: Thank you for your kind addition. I have done this too, but Kaspersky Filter seems to be protected by a daemon process, whether I choose Make Service Inactive or delete the service directly, it will be restarted and activated immediately.

Comment: @AppleGreen Then you have to uninstall Kaspersky, since Network Filters are the fundamental mode of operation for these apps, if you disable it it's not really doing anything.

Comment: I don't think it is necessary for an anti-virus software to filter network content, the file anti-virus function is enough for me. I think it's a terrible thing that my network traffic is audited by some software first. I can't even tell if this audit is only happening on my laptop or Kaspersky's server.

Comment: Is there a way to do this (disable/delete Network Filters) from the commandline / Terminal?